# NuxtJS value from Vuex Store undefined

Tags: javascript, vuex, nuxt.js

I've created a vuex store like this in Nuxt.

```
export const state = () => ({
  id: "",
  type: null,
  name: null,
});

export const mutations = {
  setProfile(state, profile) {
    state.id = profile.idStr;
    state.type = profile.type;
    state.name = profile.name;
  }
};

export const getters = {
  name(state) {
    return state.name;
  }
};
```

The data is stored with `store.commit("profile/setProfile", profile.data);` and successfuly set. (Values are shown in chrome dev-tools)

Now I'm trying to access the property `name` in one of my components using the `mapGetters` method like this.

```
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  computed: mapGetters({
    name: "profile/name"
  })
};
```

My problem is that the getter is not found.

```
ERROR  [vuex] unknown getter: profile/name
```

What is wrong with this approach?

Comment: Can you give an example payload to `setProfile`? Is your store within a `profile.js` file?

Comment: I've added the example. The store file is named `profile.js`

Comment: Did you figure out the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use `mapGetters` instead of `mapState`?

Comment: Thank you. I think we're on the right way. Now I get `ERROR  [vuex] unknown getter: profile/name   `

Comment: Afraid I can't help anymore for the moment sorry! Must sleep.

Comment: No, problem. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

as of now (nuxt v2.14.7) the syntax is

```
    export default {
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters({getName: 'profile/name'}),
        }
    }
```

then in the component the getter can be used as

```
    this.getName;
```